How to include certain fields in Pydantic model when setting exclude_unset=True
I am running into situation that I want to generally exclude unset fields; however, manually include some of them.
For example I have
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class A(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str = Field(default='bbb', frozen=True)
    c: str = Field(default='ccc')

x = A(a='aaa')

x.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)  # Returns {'a': 'aaa'}
x.model_dump(exclude_unset=True, include={'b'})  # Returns {}

I want to get the result of {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'} when calling model_dump, which is excluding unset fields, here b and c, but do include b as I manually put b in exception.
How can I achieve this?
Environment: python==3.12, pydantic==2.9
